# javascript riddle: 2 objects that seem identical with respect to constructor, prototype and __proto__ link, behave differently

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, ecmascript-5, prototypal-inheritance

I am an experienced object oriented programmer but this got me!  Why am I able to do new f() but not new a().  I will appreciate any pointers.

```
 // first a few facts 
if (Object instanceof Function) console.log("Object isa Function");
console.log("Function.prototype is " + Function.prototype);
/* output
 Object isa Function
  Function.prototype is function Empty() {}
*/

var f = new Function();
console.log("Prototype of f:" + f.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of f:" + f.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of f:" + f.__proto__);
if (f instanceof Function) console.log("f isa Function");
/* output
Prototype of f:[object Object]
Constructor of f:function Function() { [native code] }
Prototype Link of f:function Empty() {}
 f isa Function
*/


function A() {}
console.log("Prototype of A:" + A.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of A:" + A.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of A:" + A.__proto__);
if (A instanceof Function) console.log("A isa Function");
/*
Prototype of A:[object Object]
Constructor of A:function Function() { [native code] }
Prototype Link of A:function Empty() {}
A isa Function
*/

 // contruct a
var a = new A();
console.log("Prototype of a:" + a.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of a:" + a.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of a:" + a.__proto__);
if (a instanceof Function) console.log("a isa Function");
if (a instanceof A) console.log("a isa A");
/* output
 Prototype of a:undefined
Constructor of a:function A(){}
Prototype Link of a:[object Object]
a isa A
*/

console.log("~~~~~b constructed as new f()");
var b = new f();
console.log("Prototype of b:" + b.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of b:" + b.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of b:" + b.__proto__);
/* output
 ~~~~~b constructed as new f()
Prototype of b:undefined
Constructor of b:function anonymous() {}
Prototype Link of b:[object Object]
*/

console.log("~~~~~b constructed as new a()");
a.prototype = Object.prototype;
a.constructor = Function;
a.__proto__ = Function.prototype;
if (a instanceof Function) console.log("a isa Function");
console.log("Prototype of a:" + a.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of a:" + a.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of a:" + a.__proto__);
/* output
~~~~~b constructed as new a()
a isa Function
Prototype of a:[object Object]
Constructor of a:function Function() { [native code] }
Prototype Link of a:function Empty() {}     
*/
b = new a();
/* ERROR  Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function*/
```

I have done my best to provide the output as well.  notice that f and a are identical in terms of prototype, constructor and prototype link.  Why does the ERROR appear when I try to new a() in the last line?

Comment: "new " needs a function, _a_ is an object instance of the _A_ constructor

Comment: You're expecting there to be a "prototype" property of an instantiated object, but that's incorrect. *edit* yes and as @dandavis says, objects aren't functions and can't be used as constructors.

Comment: Constructors are Objects and Functions, when called as constructors they return a plain Object (by default), not a Function. Plain Objects have a private `[[Prototype]]` but no public *prototype* (by default), Functions have both.

Comment: Dandavis, a isa function as pointed ut in the code

Comment: Pointy,  I have explicitly set the prototype property of the instantiated object as you can see in the code.

Comment: RobG, Please elaborate.  I have explicitly set the prototype property.  So how does the interpretor differentiate between an instance and an object definition? Especially because Object instance of Function is TRUE.

Comment: As stated before; f is tyoeof function and a is not (case sensitive) only function types can be used with new to create new instances. Maybe the following can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Comment: Object is a function because you can do new Object but the result of new Object is an Object instance, not a function. New Function will get you an instance of type Function so you can use new on the result of new Function

Comment: HMR,  thanks for the link.  Its a good one.

Answer (score 1):

As the error points out, `a` is expected to be a **function**, that is, it must be callable. The `new` keyword requires a function object that knows how to construct an instance - but `a` does not. Letting it inherit from `Function.prototype` (by using `__proto__`) does not help anything, callability is an intrinsic property of objects.

You are able to call `new f()`, as `f` *is*  such a constructor function, being created by the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Comment: Bergi, Thanks for some useful information.  Is there a good place to read about the intrinsic property of javascript objects?  I want to gain a fundamental understanding as opposed to a functional understanding.  Thanks again!

Comment: You can always [read the spec](http://es5.github.io/), specifically [§8.6.2 Object Internal Properties and Methods](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2) (`new` uses `[[construct]]`). If you need a more extensive explanation, Dmitry Soshnikov has written a very good series [*EcmaScript in detail*](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-7-2-oop-ecmascript-implementation/), also (however apparantly unfinished) [on ES5](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-0-introduction/).

Comment: Thanks very much. Surprised how little there is on this subject.  Maybe a simple isCallable() implementation is necessary.  from the document you suggested I interpret that  [[Callable]] is an internal property that needs to be set for an object to be called as a function or through the new operator.  [[Construct]]  on the other hand is just what is usually implemented as a constructor pointer?  in other words my original problem was that the constructor for a was not callable?  or a itself is not callable or both?

Comment: I might've oversimplified my answer. Calling `x()` (or using `.call()` etc) will result in `[[call]]` being used, or - if the object in question is not callable, i.e. has no `[[call]]` internal property - an exception being thrown. This can trivially be tested by using [`typeof x == "function"`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3). However, writing `new x` will call the `[[construct]]` internal property. All user-defined functions (such as `f` or `A`) [have this property](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2). Plain user-created objects (`a`, `b`, `{}`) have neither [[call]] nor [[construct]].

Comment: According to the spec typeof return "function" if the argument implements [[Call]].  Is there a similar test for [[Construct]]?  Thanks again.

Comment: No, the only thing you can do is something like `try { new x; return true } catch (e) { return e instanceof TypeError }`

Comment: Thank you Bergi.  Your comments were great help.  Most importantly you understood the question precisely. Congratulations,  I think you have a very good grasp on the fundamentals of javascript and can express your knowledge very clearly.  Best Regards,

Comment: Oh, btw: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/add-reflect-isconstructor-and-reflect-iscallable and https://esdiscuss.org/topic/isconstructor :-)